# Unable to paginate on a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to paginate on a call to callback function but getting an error over second call

my function does:

```
        let content = ''

    let size = 100
    let from = 1

    function result(size, from, callback) {
        api.performRequest('/myContents', 'GET', {
            pageSize: size,
            startFrom: from,
            filter:'NOT contents:[* TO *]',
        }, function (data) {
            content += JSON.stringify(data)
            callback()
        })
    }

    function logContent() {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(content)
        console.log('content length: ', parsed.body.length)

        if (parsed.body.length === size) {
            calculate(size, from + size)
        }
    }

    function calculate(size, from) {
        result(size, from, logContent)
    }

    calculate(size, from)
```

on the first call the console returns

> content length:  100

on the second call I get all my json chunk on the logs and an error

> Unexpected token { in JSON at position 32847

I think it has to do with the callback and something happening before the function finishes, but I'm unable to see what I'm doing wrong here

the function performRequest just does an http get and returns a json chunk

```
export function performRequest(endpoint, method, data, callback) {

const headers = {
    Authorization: auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Location,ETag',
}

let options = {
    host: host,
    port: port,
    path: endpoint,
    headers: headers,
}

if (method === 'GET') {
    endpoint += '?' + queryString.stringify(data)
    const additionalOptions = {
        path: endpoint,
    }

    options = _.merge(options, additionalOptions)
}

return http.get(options, function (response) {
    // Continuously update stream with data
    let body = ''
    response.on('data', function (d) {
        body += d
    })
    response.on('end', function () {

        // Data reception is done
        const parsed = JSON.parse(body)
        callback({
            totalCount: parsed.totalCount,
            body: parsed.content,
        })
    })
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call is going to be fine, because your content is empty at first. So, during the first call:

```
content = '' --> content = '{...}'
```

And your second call :

```
content = '{...}' --> content = '{...}{...}'
```

Thus the error :

> Unexpected token { in JSON at position 32847

You need to put every objects in an array, or even in another object if you want it to work. You can create an array and `push` every element into it at every call.

Comment: You are totally right, tkx a lot @Ksyqo. reseting the content or using an array both worked fine.